# matplotlib histogram x-ticks wrong values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have histogram subplots that present only the amount of "0" and "1" values. I don't understand why my "1" values bar is in x-value "0.9", instead of "1"?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=7, ncols=4, figsize=(25, 40), tight_layout=True)  

for ax, i in zip(axes.ravel(), IND):

    ax.hist(df.loc[df.RESP == 1, i].values, color='r')
    ax.hist(df.loc[df.RESP == 0, i].values, color='b')
```

Where `df` is DataFrame, `IND` is list of DataFrame columns, `RESP` as well as the other columns in `IND` take only "0" and "1" values. The first three plots are shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please show the code you used to generate these charts as a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Without this information it's difficult to guess what is wrong.

Comment: I changed the original question. I hope it's clear now. Thanks in advance!